# Python, Averages, and Division

Tags: python, types, average, division

```
first = float(input("Enter first number: "));
second = float(input("Enter second number: "));
avg = float((first + second) / 2);
print(str(avg));
```

Using the numbers 1.1 and 1.3 as inputs, the expected output is 1.2. However, the result I'm receiving is 1.2000000000000002. I understand that this is related to Python and it's datatypes.

However, I'm unsure of how to evaluate this correctly, or why this specific result is achieved.

**EDIT: Python 3.2**

Comment: which python version is yours? I have 2.6.6 and with the same inputs I get 1.2

Comment: @cjdcordeiro: Python 3, judging by the `print()` function.

Comment: This is not a python thing really, this is a IEEE float thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [decimals](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial):

```
import decimal

first = decimal.Decimal('1.1')
second = decimal.Decimal('1.3')
avg = (first + second) / 2
print(avg)
```